# не отображается wp_footer()

Tags: wordpress

на сайте выводится и работает wp_head() но  wp_footer() не отображается

```
 <?php wp_footer(); ?></body></html>
```

вот файл index.php

```
{
add_action('wp-footer', 'scripts_theme');

function scripts_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_style('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/slick/slick.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/slick/slick-theme.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('bt', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('calc', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/calc.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('mask', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.maskinput.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/slick/slick.js');
}
}
```

вот что нахочдится в function.php
помогите пожалуйста с проблемой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может подойдет изменение wp-footer на wp_footer в функции add_action?

C:

```
add_action('wp-footer', 'scripts_theme');
```

На :

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'scripts_theme');
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, иногда глаза замыливаются и уже просто не видно банальных опечаток)

Comment: @WeBDevelopeR если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решением

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно подключаете скрипты. Скрипты и стили должны подключаться на хук `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Так же, если вы хотите, чтобы скрипты подключались в футере, тогда необходимо указать последним параметром true. Подробнее в документации: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_theme' );
function scripts_theme(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', [], true ); // true - говорит о том, что нужно подключить скрипты в футере. (Работает только для скриптов)
}
```

Comment: А ТС что, не так подключает? ;)

Comment: Хук посмотри) не тот хук

Comment: Хук не "не тот", а "отличный от большинства мануалов". Но вполне нормальный. :)  https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_enqueue_scripts